# Interlaced Image with RMagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

ImageMagick has [an interlace option](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Image.html#interlacetype), which `RMagick supports`, but I can't work out the syntax for this. I can see [`Magick::InterlaceType` and `Magick::LineInterlace`](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/constants.html#InterlaceType) are both valid constants, but how to save an image using those constants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RMagick'

img = Magick::Image.new(300, 50) do
  self.background_color = '#FFFF00'
end
img.write('test.jpg') { self.interlace = Magick::PlaneInterlace }

#check the interlace property
puts img.interlace # PlaneInterlace
```